# What if Database Size Limit exceeds?

Tags: mysql, limit

I was just thinking if a mysql database's size limit exceeds what will happen to my app running on that.
My hosting only allows 1 GB of space per database. I know thats too much, but what if i make an app on people discussing something, and sometime after many years the database limit exceeds.

Then what will I do? And approximately how much text data can be stored in 1 GB?
And can I have 2 databases running one application. Like one database contains usernames and profiles and that sort of stuff, and the other contains questions and answers? And will that slow down process of getting everything?

Update: can i set up mysql on my own server and have overcome the size limitation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There will be no speed disadvantage from splitting your tables across two databases (assuming both databases are on the same MySQL server), but if the data are logically part of the same application then it is more sensible they be grouped together.
- When you want to refer to a table in another database, you also have to qualify it with the appropriate database name, which you could see as an inefficiency.
- My guess is that if you approach 1GB with two databases or with one, it's not going to make a difference how your host treats you (it shouldn't make a difference for MySQL, after all). I suggest you not worry about it unless you're going to be generating data like nobody's business, and in that case you require a more dedicated host.
- If you figure out years down the line that you're coming to the limit, you can make a decision then whether to dump some of your older data or move to a host that permits you to store more data.
- I don't think your application would stop working immediately when you hit 1GB. I think it more likely that your host would start writing you emails telling you off and suggesting you upgrade packages, or something.

Answer (score 2):

Most of this is specific to your host.  1GB is ~1 billion bytes (one letter usually = on byte).  Having 2 databases will not slow anything down, so long as they're both on the same host and they're properly set up.

Comment: and what if i have like two databases with the same coloums like i also have usernames and also the questions and answers in both... then it would have to look into both right? and then it would slow down? thanks for your answer...

Comment: You can have the same exact table in different databases, but there's generally no benefit of doing so.  Regarding your update, you can definitely setup a database on your local server and access it from your host.  Just make sure your connection info is correct on the host code, and your mysql.users table has you're host listed as allowed to access your mysql instance.